# How to restrict access to /mini-profiler-resources/results-index per request

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvc-mini-profiler

The examples for restricting access to the mini-profiler resources all happen in the `Application_Start` method which is confusing since this will globally turn `on/off` the `profiler` for everyone based on the access of the 1st person to access the site.

Later on in the examples, they show how to abandon `profiler` info based on each request which is enabling it globally then denying per request but this doesn't work on the `/results-index` page.

Is there a way to only allow access the `/results-index` page per request, or to abandon this `info/page` in a similar way?

Comment: Didn't realize that it was just assigning the delegate to call later on, I used an anonymous delegate to test with which shouldn't have made a difference but I believe I got this to work now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I do it:
Have all controllers inherit from a common `BaseController` class.
In `BaseController`, override `Initialize`:

```
protected override void Initialize(RequestContext requestContext)
{
    if (requestContext.HttpContext.User == null || !requestContext.HttpContext.User.IsInRole(KnownRoles.Developer.ToString()))
    {
        MiniProfiler.Stop(discardResults: true);
    }
    base.Initialize(requestContext);
}
```

Edit: You can restrict access to the miniprofiler history page in your web.config:

```
  <location path="mini-profiler-resources">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="Developer"/>
        <deny users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

This will allow only users with the "Developer" role to access that page.

Comment: This will abandon the widget displayed in the page but wont affect the "last 100 profiled" items page /results-index

Comment: Edited my answer with the solution for the index page. This should work if you want to restrict access based on roles, or individual users.

Comment: Thanks for the update. When I tested this I used an anonymous delegate without parameters which I believe caused it to run only once in the app_onstart. When I switched to a delegate matching the signature in the examples page it worked as expected.